# Slow MySQL queries using SUM()

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have to run two queries in my code to get my tenants balance. However, these queries are too slow.

First query, I get all the tenants and it's unit name:

```
SELECT t.TenantID 
  FROM Tenants t
  JOIN Units u
    ON t.UnitID = u.UnitID
 Where t.Prospect = 2 
   AND t.PropertyID = 8
 ORDER 
    BY CONCAT(Left(Replace(UnitName,'-',''),2),
              REPEAT('0', (10-CHAR_LENGTH(UnitName))),
              Right(Replace(UnitName,'-',''),
                    CHAR_LENGTH(Replace(UnitName,'-',''))-2
             )     )
```

It returns 500 rows

Then I get the balances in 4 conditions. This query will be inside of first query loop:

```
Select
        SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 1 AND ChargeTypeID != 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS TotalDebit,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 1 AND ChargeTypeID = 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS HousingDebit,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 2 AND ChargeTypeID != 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCredit,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 2 AND ChargeTypeID = 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS HousingCredit
    From TenantTransactions
    Where TenantID= FirstQuery.TenantID
```

Am I doing the queries wrong? It's taking like 1 minute to run.

Comment: Have you indexed your tables?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: You have too many function calls inside your query. This is definitely a cause for slow response. However, to have a better. Solution, you will need to specify the table structure, indexes and keys

Comment: Yes, Tenants and TenantTransactions tables are linked by TenantID. TenantID is Tenants PK and TenantTransactions FK

Comment: Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Please pay special attention to the section on query performance. Please [edit] your question to provide the basic information we need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in a single query with `GROUP BY`.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t.TenantID, TotalDebit, HousingDebit, TotalCredit, HousingCredit
  FROM Tenants t
  JOIN Units u ON t.UnitID = u.UnitID
  LEFT JOIN (
        Select
          TenantID,
          SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 1 AND ChargeTypeID != 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS TotalDebit,
          SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 1 AND ChargeTypeID = 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS HousingDebit,
          SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 2 AND ChargeTypeID != 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCredit,
          SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 2 AND ChargeTypeID = 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS HousingCredit
        From TenantTransactions
       Group By TenantID
       ) sums ON sums.TenantID = t.TenantID
 Where t.Prospect = 2 
   AND t.PropertyID = 8
 ORDER 
    BY CONCAT(Left(Replace(UnitName,'-',''),2),REPEAT('0', (10-CHAR_LENGTH(UnitName))),Right(Replace(UnitName,'-',''),CHAR_LENGTH(Replace(UnitName,'-',''))-2))
```

The inner query may still run for a while but it will only run once.

Try a compound covering index on `TenantTransactions` containing these columns: `(TenantID, TransactionTypeID, ChargeTypeID, TransactionAmount)` to optimize the query with the SUMs in it.

Try a compound index on `Tenants` with the columns `(PropertyID, Prospect)` in it.

Comment: Thank you... It runs very fast. For some reason, some of the balance returns different value from the my slow queries.

Comment: Did you figure out what caused your data discrepancy?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Your query is perfect. I changed one where condition. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it with a subquery.  You know, the performance problem might not be database performance, but the back and forth between your database and application server.  So that is where a single query will help.

```
SELECT t.TenantID,
  (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 1 AND ChargeTypeID != 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) From TenantTransactions TT WHERE TT.TenantID=t.TenantID) AS TotalDebit,
  (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 1 AND ChargeTypeID = 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) From TenantTransactions TT WHERE TT.TenantID=t.TenantID) AS HousingDebit,
  (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 2 AND ChargeTypeID != 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) From TenantTransactions TT WHERE TT.TenantID=t.TenantID) AS TotalCredit,
  (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 2 AND ChargeTypeID = 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) From TenantTransactions TT WHERE TT.TenantID=t.TenantID) AS HousingCredit  
  FROM Tenants t
  JOIN Units u
    ON t.UnitID = u.UnitID
 Where t.Prospect = 2 
   AND t.PropertyID = 8
 ORDER 
    BY CONCAT(Left(Replace(UnitName,'-',''),2),REPEAT('0', (10-CHAR_LENGTH(UnitName))),Right(Replace(UnitName,'-',''),CHAR_LENGTH(Replace(UnitName,'-',''))-2))
```

Comment: had extra comma in there.  It is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, but it still returning syntax error because the END inside the CASE. I'm using MySQL